# Is it possible to use wpa passphrase hash in cloud-init's network-config file?

Tags: wireless, 20.04, wpa-supplicant, cloud-init, passphrase

As the title states I'd like to obfuscate my wifi's credentials and know that wpa supplicant has wpa_passphrase to do this.

My question is can I place wpa_passphrase's hashed output in the entry for password of the network-config file that Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS uses?

Or is there a similar command to hash the psk for cloud-init files that I should be using instead?

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that cloud-init on Ubuntu uses sha-512 for password encryption. One way to generate one is to use the openssl  command in a terminal: openssl passwd -6

The "-6" says use SHA-512. While you can put a password on the command line, leaving it off is more secure since it won't show up in logs or in .bash_history. When you leave off the password to be encrypted, it will ask you for the password and again to verify it. Nothing shows up on your terminal as you type and verity the password.

The command will generate the encrypted password with a random salt using the format $6$salt$LongEncryptedPassword similar to this

`$6$ThisIsRandomSalt$TheEncryptedPasswordWillBeALongAlphaNumericString`

Instead of using the keyword "password" in the network-config YAML file, use "hashed_password".